# How to remove decimals from tab delimited files Excel

Tags: excel, csv

Want to thank you for taking the time to read my question.

My excel file, the cells are rounded to two decimals, but when I save a tab delimited file format, some fields actually have many decimals, even though they're not visible in the excel cells.

Was hoping someone can please help me out.

I'm using tab delimited files which are uploaded to mysql.

Please note that I am not a programmer! Thanks much everyone!

Answer (score 1):

The real value in the cell seems not to be rounded, but only formated to 2 decimals. If you export, the format is ignored and the real value is exported.
To avoid that, I suggest to add the ROUND-formular to the cell.

```
=ROUND(YOUR VALUE;2)
```

2 = number of decimals

YOUR VALUE can be the other cell or the calculation.

Regards

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yes, I formatted the cells which is not the same as the real numbers. 

My spreadsheet has like 20 columns and like 400 rows, and there are many spreadsheets... Is it possible to run a macro to force the rounding to two decimal places for a specified range? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Dim ThisCell As Range
For Each ThisCell In Range("B2:X260")
ThisCell.Value = Application.Round(ThisCell.Value, 2)
Next ThisCell